# Error: Unable to access jarfile sailfin-installer-v1-b60g-linux.jar

Tags: java, linux

When i install sailfin server on ubuntu, i try to run command:

```
~$ java -Xmx256m -jar sailfin-installer-v1-b60g-linux.jar
```

But i get an error message:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile sailfin-installer-v1-b60g-linux.jar

I've installed `jdk7` and find this problem.

What else should I be doing?

Comment: You're using `–` (a dash, U+2013) instead of `-` (a hyphen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy-pasted the options from somewhere. The `–` in `–Xmx256m` is not actually a hyphen `-` but a different character which looks similar. Retype it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just started to learn about linux. I've fixed the character as you say but i get a new message
 
  "Error: Unable to access jarfile sailfin-installer-v1-b60g-linux.jar"

What should i do?

Comment: This seems like a permissions problem

Comment: Is the jar file in your home directory? If not, look at the path of the directory it's in, and before the java command run `cd path-goes-here`